# How to read parameter value which sent through Chat Control (iframe) from bot

Tags: node.js, iframe, botframework, web-chat

I have integrated a ms bot framework webchat(node js) in to a web page. I am  passing the logged in user information by using iframe.

Eg: Like below

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/
testbot?s=secret_code&username=admin&userid=1234'></iframe>
```

Could anyone guide me, how can I read these parameter values from bot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Maadi! Welcome to SO. I don't think what will work, though I could be wrong. But you try embedding the bot using Javascript. That gives you control to send data with a specific user id. Not sure about the username though.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a username and userid in the iframe's query parameters, then the activity's .From property will have those values:

```
<iframe style="width:300px;height:400px;" src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/mybotid?s=mybotsecret&username=adminxxx&userid=1234'></iframe>
```

[image]